# Where are the drivers for Windows computers located on an Android phone?

Tags: usb-drivers

Im talking about the drivers that install when you plug your phone into a Windows computer.

Comment: Windows comes either pre loaded with fitting (generic) drivers or you'd need to download them from the manufacturer. But all this heavily depends on your device' make/model.

Comment: Which specific phone are you asking about here?

Answer (score 2):

They're not stored anywhere on your phone. Windows [finds and downloads them](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware) from Windows Update when you plug your device in. If an appropriate driver has already been downloaded and installed previously (or shipped with the Windows installation), it will use that and skip the download step.

Without Internet, and in the absence of an appropriate driver already being present on disk somewhere, the driver installation will end up failing.

Comment: What about when there isn't any internet? ( just asking)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN: If Windows already has a driver downloaded that it thinks is "appropriate" then it will use that. For example, multiple Nexus devices could use the same Google ADB driver. Otherwise the driver installation just fails, as far as I recall. You'd have to either connect to the Internet or manually install a driver you had on hand (on a disk, etc).

Comment: 10-4.  Just some more info to help others out. Thanx. :)

Comment: Drivers are actually frequently stored on device mass storage, and can even be picked up and installed by Windows automatically.